# XOR multiplication and order of arithmetic operations

Tags: math, bitwise-operators, xor

I have a dumb question, and I am embarrassed to even ask.
Due to my little knowledge in math I couldn't figure out what should I search.

I'm dealing with the following equation:

`[(a*x)^b]*c=d`

where `^` stands for **XOR** and `*` for **Multiplication**.

How can I isolate x?

Comment: Actually, it depends. What's the algebraic structure in which you do this? If they are fixed-width bitvectors, then division is not the inverse of multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[(a*x)^b]*c=d
[(a*x)^b]=d/c
(a*x)^b^b=(d/c)^b  //double xor with b retrieves initial value
(a*x)=(d/c)^b
x = ((d/c)^b) / a
```

Comment: Well, not normal algebraic means, but if you're crafty enough, you know a trick to bypass the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Based on properties of xor the following holds:

```
A xor A = 0
B xor 0 = B
```

Plus, it's commutative. The rest is plain equation solving math.